# Undefined variable: jum (View: C:\laragon\www\mobilenew\resources\views\home.blade.php)

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I want to display monthly financial data at this time with Laravel. but I had an error.

here's my controller

```
$data = pesanan::where('status_pesanan','5')->whereDate('created_at',date('m'))->get();
```

status_pesanan is order status if 5 orders are completed

The following is the code in the view

```
@foreach($rute as $rt)
  <?php $total = array(); ?>
  @foreach($data->where('kode_rute1',$rt->kode_rute) as $caritotal)
  <?php
    $total[] = $caritotal->total_bayar;
    $jum = array_sum($total);
    ?>
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

total_bayar is the revenue from the order

$rute is the looping table for the store branch

please help me for fix this.

Comment: please show the error message

Comment: yes at my title

Answer (score 0):

You havent declared the variable $jum globally and assigned it as an array. This will always return error because it hasnt been set.

So, try declaring the variable globally.

```
<?php
    $jum=null;
?>

@foreach($rute as $rt)
  <?php $total = array(); ?>
  @foreach($data->where('kode_rute1',$rt->kode_rute) as $caritotal)
  <?php
    $total[] = $caritotal->total_bayar;
    $jum = array_sum($total);
    ?>
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Edit: Why are you using $jum inside two loops? This means that eveytime it is looped $jum will be modified.

Comment: This did solve the error, but I want to display the total data from sales in each branch that I looped in the $rute variable.

Comment: This question is not related to your main question

Comment: oh yeah sorry, because someone asked what the error happened, so I wrote it in the title of the question.